# Why references can not be reinitialized in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Why references can not be reinitialized in C++ while pointers can be reinitialized?

```
int x=5;
int y=6;
int *p1;
p1 = &x;
p1 = &y; //re-initializing the pointer but same can not be done with references
int &r1 =x;//can be initialized only once
```

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305055/reference-initialization-in-c

Comment: Very short answer: because if they where, they will have exactly duplicated pointer functionality (mutable redirection)

Answer (score 1):

There's no obvious syntax. You can't use the normal `=` syntax; that sets the value the underlying pointer of the reference. Perhaps you could think up a syntax like this:

```
&my_reference = new_value;
```

But that's kind of strange and awkward.

Comment: That's not possible in any form. `&variable` is always a rvalue, and rvalues can't be the left operand of an assignment.

Comment: @Nbr44 I think you mean rvalue, since the name lvalue stems from that it usually stands on the left hand side of an assignment.

Comment: Ooopsies, rvalue indeed ! Thanks !

Comment: @Nbr44: I know it's not possible. I was saying such a feature was left out of the language at least partially because of the lack of obvious syntax. I then listed a possible sample of what it *could* look like, but then pointed out that it would be, in my words, “strange and awkward,” which I claimed is why it was not chosen. I never stated that this was supported syntax.

Comment: Alright, I misunderstood - my apologies ! I think there's also quite a technical aspect to why it was left out though. I can't see that kind of mechanism working well with the C/C++ internal side...