# Initializing reference to istream

Tags: c++, reference

I am trying to write my program so that it can process either StdIn or a file specified on the command line.

I'm doing this by trying to initialize a reference to an `istream` to either refer to `cin` or an `ifstream`, using a conditional.

*(similar techniques are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882995/how-to-declare-a-reference-and-initialize-later) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305055/reference-initialization-in-c))*

But when I try with `ifstream`, I seem to get an error that the basic_istream move-constructor is declared `protected`.

```
istream& refToCIN  ( cin );                      // This is OK
const istream& refToFile = ifstream(args[1]);    // This is OK

const istream& inStream ( FileIsProvided()? ifstream(args[1]) : cin );
// This causes error:
// std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_istream' : 
// cannot access protected member declared in class std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>

ProcessStream(inStream); // This could either be a file or cin
```

Can this be reasonably done this way?  Is there a good alternative I'm overlooking?

Comment: `ifstream(args[1])` creates a temporary. You can't bind non-const reference to it. And your first example (reftofile) defines a function, not an object.

Comment: I added `const`, but it does not change the essential problem.

Comment: Yes, I will explain in the answer.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706480/why-does-stdistringstream-appear-to-resolve-differently-to-stdifstream-in-th

Comment: @abelenky Is `FileIsProvided()` usable as `constexpr` actually?

Comment: I wonder who downvoted / VTCed the question. There is nothing inherently wrong with it.

Comment: I suspect the VTC was by a "rage-voter".  My questions are frequently down-voted by someone who I suspect has a grudge against me.

Comment: @SergeyA Well, it was me. I'm not a _rage voter_ or alike. Besides I grip what's the problem asked for is, the question clearly misses to provide a [MCVE]. This could be easily improved.

Comment: That code is very nearly ready to compile as is.  Everyone else understood it.  Here's your [***MCVE***](http://ideone.com/CJ7vl5)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I know you are not. I do not neccessarily agree with you here, but we don't have to agree on everything, do we? :)

Comment: @SergeyA _"do we? :)"_ Certainly not. I'm just failing at occasional times with my judgments though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is following:

Your left-hand side of the ternary operator is a temporary (rvalue). However, your right hand-side is an lvalue (`cin` is an lvalue). As a result, compiler is trying to create a temporary out of `cin`, and fails because of copy constructor being not available.

As for the sultions - you can simply replace `rdbuf()` of cin with `rdbuf()` of your file, and use `cin` everywhere.

---

Here's the ultimate solution OP came up with:

```
ifstream file;
std::streambuf* old_cin_buf = cin.rdbuf(); // Store the old value
if (FileIsProvided())
{
    file.open(args[1]);
    old_cin_buf = cin.rdbuf(file.rdbuf()); // Replace the ReadBuffer on cin.
    // Store the previous value as well.
}
// Use cin for all operations now.  It will either use the File or StdIn as appropriate.
...
// Restore the original value, in case it was changed by using a file.
cin.rdbuf(old_cin_buf); // This is better be done before file object here goes out of scope
```

Comment: Forgive the edit, but I wanted to show my final solution based on your answer, without a separate post.

Comment: @abelenky - edit forgiven :) One thing though - you better to replace the rdbuf back before closing the file.

Comment: Alright, now my answer is downvoted. Can the venerable downvoter please provide the reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because you don't *need* a ternary conditional or reference here.

As a matter of convention, many programs use `-` to denote `stdin` rather than omitting a filename. That's one possible avenue. On a similar line of thought, I would use Boost.ProgramOptions or `getopt` instead of manually parsing the command line. This will indirectly solve your XY problem as it'll make the `FileIsProvided()` function redundant and you'll be getting your options via other methods than using `argv[1]` directly.

If you have C++11, there's smart pointers or `std::reference_wrapper`, which allows you to "reseat" references.

As a anti-motivator, consider that classes like [`ostream_joiner`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner) keep a pointer to their internal stream objects, *not* a reference. Besides, I doubt that you enjoy the thought of having to deal with dangling references from innocuous looking code.

Otherwise...

```
if (FileIsProvided())
{
    std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
    if (ifs)
    {
        ProcessStream(ifs);
    }
} else {
    ProcessStream(std::cin);
}
```

Comment: I don't intend to import the Boost libraries when the entire, finished program is only 70 lines long, and compiles to 20K.   In a larger-scale program this may be advisable.  But when the whole thing fits on screen at once, I don't mind managing a few items myself.